# django all-auth authenticating via twitch

Tags: python, django, twitch

I am trying to authenticate a user from twitch Auth using Django and reactjs. I am able to authorize the user and store its details in the Django admin from backend but not sure how to do it from reactjs.

What I tried so far:

Following the documents from here: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

I configured everything as:

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',  
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitch',    
    'django_extensions',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = app-name.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sphinx.wsgi.application'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

I also registered the social application in the Django admin.

When I hit:

http://localhost:8000/accounts/twitch/login/

It takes me to the twitch authorization page, Which when I click on "Authorize" saves the user details in the Django admin redirects me back to the url:

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/profile/
```

The problem is I need to make sure the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL page '/accounts/profile/' has some authentication so only the logged in user can access it and to display the username of that user.

How do I authenticate the user? Like how do I send the access_token to the front-end reactjs and verify the user?

Comment: Like with registration directly via your website, you need to generate the user token during the account signup phase. You will want to subclass the [`DefaultSocialAccountAdapter`](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#creating-and-populating-user-instances), to generate the token during the `save_user()` phase.

Comment: @dirkgroten pretty naïve here, could you please elaborate on it or perhaps an example would help a lot!

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a custom auth schema, you can use the @login_required decorator before the view.